# Google Analytics: only give permission to view specific events

Tags: google-analytics

I would like to allow contextual advertisers to view the statistics of some specific events.

Is it possible in Google Analytics to give permissions to a user to only view specific events?

Answer (score 1):

Well you could create a view where you filter out everything except those events and give them permissions only for that view. That sound impractical, though.

I would rather suggest you create a custom report for that event and have it mailed once a week or so to your publishers (you will find the mail facility in the top menu where it says, well, 'email').

Comment: Eike one of these days you need to contact me.

Comment: create a separate view and use filters on it, sounds very close to what I need

Comment: @DanieleB, I really suggest to go the second route, this is much easier to set up and your publishers probably won't care if they get the data via mail or via the interface. Plus you only have 25 view per property, so with a lot of publishers you will run of views pretty quick.

Comment: @DaImTo, sure, will do (we seem to run into one another a lot here in any case :-) ).

Comment: @EikePierstorff, it would be handier to access though the interface, as it's easy to compare data for different date ranges. For the moment, I have tried to create a new view, without filters, expecting to view all results as the default views. But after already 20 minutes, no data is shown yet. Is it just a matter of waiting more time?

Comment: @DanieleB, new views only work for incoming data. Historical data is not backfilled, I'm afraid.

Comment: Ok, so i guess I just need to wait more time for results to start filling